# Android Custom QuoteSpan issue

Tags: android, html, tag-handler

I'm encountering a strange issue when applying my custom QuoteSpan.
It includes all the text after this ending tag: `</quote>`. But it works when I tried to replace `<quote>...</quote>` into `<blockquote>...</blockquote>` to skip my **Custom HtmlTagHandler** and to use the default implementation of QuoteSpan by Android. See screenshots below:

Expected Result (Using the default QuoteSpan): https://i.stack.imgur.com/bADnU.png

Current Output (Using my custom QuoteSpan): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFpkz.png

**Custom HtmlTagHandler** - for unhandled html tags (for the `quote` tag)

```
package com.demoparser.http.parser;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan;
import android.text.style.StrikethroughSpan;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

import com.demoparser.util.CustomQuoteSpan;

import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class HtmlTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler {

    private static final float[] HEADER_SIZES = {
            1.5f, 1.4f, 1.3f, 1.2f, 1.1f, 1f,
    };

    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
        if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("del")) {
            if (opening) {
                start(output, new Strikethrough());
            } else {
                end(output, Strikethrough.class, new StrikethroughSpan());
            }
        } else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("pre")) {
            if (opening) {
                start(output, new Monospace());
            } else {
                end(output, Monospace.class, new TypefaceSpan("monospace"));
            }
        } else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("quote")) {
            if (opening) {
                handleP(output);
                start(output, new BlockQuote());
            } else {
                handleP(output);
                end(output, BlockQuote.class, new CustomQuoteSpan());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void handleP(Editable text) {
        int len = text.length();

        if (len >= 1 && text.charAt(len - 1) == '\n') {
            if (len >= 2 && text.charAt(len - 2) == '\n') {
                return;
            }

            text.append("\n");
            return;
        }

        if (len != 0) {
            text.append("\n\n");
        }
    }

    private static Object getLast(Spanned text, Class kind) {
        /*
         * This knows that the last returned object from getSpans()
         * will be the most recently added.
         */
        Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);

        if (objs.length == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return objs[objs.length - 1];
        }
    }

    private static void start(Editable text, Object mark) {
        int len = text.length();
        text.setSpan(mark, len, len, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
    }

    private static void end(Editable text, Class kind, Object repl) {
        int len = text.length();
        Object obj = getLast(text, kind);
        int where = text.getSpanStart(obj);

        text.removeSpan(obj);

        if (where != len) {
            text.setSpan(repl, where, len, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }

    public static class Strikethrough {}
    public static class Monospace {}
    public static class BlockQuote {}

}
```

**Custom QuoteSpan**

```
package com.demoparser.util;

/*
 * Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan;
import android.text.style.LineBackgroundSpan;

public class CustomQuoteSpan implements LeadingMarginSpan, LineBackgroundSpan {
    private static final int STRIPE_WIDTH = 5;
    private static final int GAP_WIDTH = 8;

    private final int mBackgroundColor;
    private final int mColor;

    public QuoteSpan() {
        super();
        mBackgroundColor = 0xffddf1fd;
        mColor = 0xff098fdf;
    }

    public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
        return STRIPE_WIDTH + GAP_WIDTH;
    }

    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir,
                                  int top, int baseline, int bottom,
                                  CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                                  boolean first, Layout layout) {
        Paint.Style style = p.getStyle();
        int color = p.getColor();

        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setColor(mColor);

        c.drawRect(x, top, x + dir * STRIPE_WIDTH, bottom, p);

        p.setStyle(style);
        p.setColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawBackground(Canvas c, Paint p, int left, int right, int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, int lnum) {
        int paintColor = p.getColor();
        p.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
        c.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, p);
        p.setColor(paintColor);
    }
}
```

And the HTML elements that I'm trying to apply the custom QuoteSpan:

```
<quote>
 <div class="q_b">      
  <div class="q_tl">
   <div class="q_tr">
    <div class="q_bl">
     <div class="q_br">
      <div class="q_body">
       <b class="qfont">Quote:</b>
       <div style="padding:5px;">
        <div class="q_by">
         Originally Posted by 
         <strong>: <a href="/index.php?thread=1#msg2"> username on 1-1-2016 00:00 AM</a></strong>
        </div>
        Sample Quoted Text 1
        <br>
        <br>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</quote>
<br>
<br>
This message should not be inside the QuoteSpan
```

I'm using `Html.fromHtml(...)` to render the span.

```
Html.fromHtml(message, null, new HtmlTagHandler())
```

Here's the Logs for the index of opening and closing tag:

```
START: 0
END: 138 <-- should be 87
```

Anyone have any idea to achieve the same result as the default QuoteSpan's output or point it out the wrong implementation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please Try It : http://takeoffandroid.com/android-views/android-spannable-text-view-to-change-color-size-style-and-adding-click-event-for-particular-word/

Comment: your `QuoteSpan` works OK, the bug is inside custom  `Html.TagHandler` (i didn't have time to locate it)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm currently using `Html.fromHtml(...)` to show the span. I already tried using `SpannableString` but there's some instances that the `quote` tag is nested (including other tags) and need to look for its child nodes.

Comment: It seems like an issue with `HtmlToSpannedConverter` of [Html.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java), it passes the wrong `mSpannableStringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25836810/5766344), prepending `&zwj;` ([Zero-width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) - a non-printing character) as a workaround solved the issue.

```
&zwj;<quote>...</quote>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Custom Quote Span use the Quote Span class constructor that accepts a Parcel and use this Java code :

```
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
parcel.writeInt(getColor(R.color.colorAccent));//stripe color
parcel.writeInt(10);//stripe width
parcel.writeInt(10);//gap width
parcel.setDataPosition(0);
QuoteSpan quoteSpan = new QuoteSpan(parcel);
SpannableString string = new  SpannableString(getString(R.string.top_review));
string.setSpan(quoteSpan, 0, string.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.quoteSpan)).setText(string);
parcel.recycle(); // put the parcel object back in the pool
```

If you want in Kotlin see this Repository :
[Custom Android Quote Span with AppCompat support](https://github.com/sourin00/Android-Quote-Span-with-AppCompat-)